# traversal css syntax error and confusion

Tags: css

```
<div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="#">    
                        <li class="title other">0-9</li>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
```

why it doesn't work like this? I don't want to use any class for the `<li>`

```
.panel-title a li{

}
```

Comment: Because the HTML is invalid?

Answer (score 3):

That is because `<li>` has to be under `<ul>`

### And

`<a>` cannot have `<ul>`

### Your HTML is therefore invalid

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is correct.

The HTML is wrong:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#">    
            <ul>
                <li class="title other">0-9</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

You can't write down a `<li>` tag without its parent `<ul>` tag.